# awk print data based on character lengths

Tags: awk

#Revised question.

The second column in a table contains characters from 5 to 30 in lengths, and it looks like this;

[image]

If I want to extract the rows with characters with 5 letters in length, I use

```
awk 'length($2)==5 { print }' input.tabular > output.tabular
```

So the resulting "length_5.tabular" file will extract only the following rows from the original file
AAKNN 
AATKP

,whereas "length_6.tabular" file will extract the only row of
AAKKPP \

How can I loop this, so that I can get 26 files according to character lengths (i.e., `length_5.tabular`, `length_6.tabular` ... `length_30.tabular`)?
I want columns for each extracted row to be included in the resulting file.

Comment: `extract only the peptide sequences 5mers in length` would be generally understandable by more people as `extract only the strings 5 characters in length`, assuming that's what you mean since that's what your script does. Try to avoid domain-specific language when explaining a problem so more people are able to help you. [edit] your question to provide a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can  help you. Also tell us how large the input file is in terms of lines as there can be vast differences in execution time between potential solutions.

Comment: Post text for your sample input/output, not images. We can't test a potential solution using an image for input. Also, don't just post the specific column that contains the data, show the context too, ie at least 1 column before/after it if such exists. And again - tell us about how many lines long your real input file will be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about peptide sequences, but I guess this is what you want:

```
awk '{
  fname=length($2) "mer.output.tabular"
  print >> fname
  close(fname)
}' input.tabular
```